# How to delete inaccessible data on root ZFS dataset?

Tags: freebsd, zfs, network-attached-storage

I have a mirrored ZFS array on a FreeBSD that I used for home NAS, consisting of a 6TB internal drive and a 8TB external USB drive.  I have 2TB of space occupied that should not be occupied, but I cannot delete or even see any of its contents.

I suspect that this originated when I was transferring a lot of relatively large (>=10GB) files when I was initially setting up my ZFS array (a la `send/receive` snapshot), but kept getting the infamous [broken pipe](https://github.com/iocage/iocage/issues/337) error when it was almost completed, and so it never finished.

I eventually transferred it successfully over LAN, but now I have ~2TB of inaccessible space in each pool, space I think corresponds to the never-completed transfer of data.  In other words, `zfs_bk` takes up 5.27 TB, but should be taking up only ~3 TB.  However, there are no files in `/zfs_bk`; the only actual files that can be seen are in the datasets mounted in the subfolders of `zfs_bk`.
*Those* datasets have sizes consistent with what is contained/displayed in their mountpoints, however.

Here is my output (happy to post more, obviously)

`zfs list`

```
NAME                   USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
zfs_bk                5.27T   612K  2.28T  /zfs_bk
zfs_bk/docs           1.23M   612K  1.23M  /zfs_bk/me/docs
zfs_bk/me             12.1G   612K  8.38G  /zfs_bk/me
zfs_bk/me/code        209M   612K   209M   /zfs_bk/me/code
zfs_bk/me/files       77.2M   612K  77.2M  /zfs_bk/me/files
zfs_bk/me/pictures    2.11G   612K  2.11G  /zfs_bk/me/pictures
zfs_bk/me/robo        1.29G   612K  1.29G  /zfs_bk/me/robo
zfs_bk/me/video         88K   612K    88K  /zfs_bk/me/video
zfs_bk/shared          369G   612K    88K  /zfs_bk/shared
zfs_bk/shared/images  2.10G   612K  2.10G  /zfs_bk/shared/images
zfs_bk/shared/music    367G   612K   367G  /zfs_bk/shared/music
zfs_bk/shared/video     88K   612K    88K  /zfs_bk/shared/video
zfs_bk/unsorted       2.61T   612K  2.61T  /zfs_bk/unsorted
zroot                 6.18G   101G    88K  /zroot
zroot/ROOT            2.59G   101G    88K  none
zroot/ROOT/default    2.59G   101G  2.59G  /
zroot/tmp               88K   101G    88K  /tmp
zroot/usr             3.58G   101G    88K  /usr
zroot/usr/home         641M   101G   641M  /usr/home
zroot/usr/ports       2.29G   101G  2.29G  /usr/ports
zroot/usr/src          682M   101G   682M  /usr/src
zroot/var             1.16M   101G    88K  /var
zroot/var/audit         88K   101G    88K  /var/audit
zroot/var/crash         88K   101G    88K  /var/crash
zroot/var/log          736K   101G   736K  /var/log
zroot/var/mail          88K   101G    88K  /var/mail
zroot/var/tmp           96K   101G    96K  /var/tmp
```

`ls -a /zfs_bk`

```
.               ..              me             shared          unsorted
```

`du -h -d=1 /zfs_bk`

```
3.0T    /zfs_bk
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have snapshots:

```
zfs list -t snapshot
```